# Does this sound natural? "We'd like to have any opportunity"

Tags: expression-choice

> We'd like to have any opportunity we can to perform on stage.

Does this sentence sound natural and idiomatic?

And if you have any, please suggest me a better alternative. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

"We'd welcome..." would be a more commonly use phrase (for this type of sentiment), or "We would take...". The "we can" is implied, since you are talking about the collective you (we). You could throw in an "available", too, but it's not necessary.

"We'd welcome/take any [available] opportunity to perform on stage."

Alternatively, you could say, "We'd take any opportunity we could get to perform on stage", if you wanted it to sound a little less eloquent.